Воспроизведение видео в Avalonia C#
Существует ли элемент управления, позволяющий воспроизводить видео в Avalonia C#?

https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/tree/3.x/samples/LibVLCSharp.Avalonia.Sample

Ответ на поверхности интернета уже есть. Тут будет ссылка на пост, и обновленные либы
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55398378/show-video-in-avalonia-ui
